# How to create function and pass control-id to show/hide

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

I want to get rid of the repeated if condition, how can i create a function and pass control id in order to show/hide specific div.

Here is the code.

```
hideNotAvailableURLS = ->
  if $('#rtsp-value:contains("Not available")').length > 0
    $('#h264-section').addClass 'hide'
  else
    $('#h264-section').removeClass 'hide'

  if $('#camera_hls span:contains("Not available")').length > 0
    $('#hls-section').addClass 'hide'
  else
    $('#hls-section').removeClass 'hide'

  if $('#camera_h264 span:contains("Not available")').length > 0
    $('#rtsp-section').addClass 'hide'
  else
    $('#rtsp-section').removeClass 'hide'

  if $('#camera_rtmp span:contains("Not available")').length > 0
    $('#rtmp-section').addClass 'hide'
  else
    $('#rtmp-section').removeClass 'hide'

  if $('#camera_link span:contains("Not available")').length > 0
    $('#camera-section').addClass 'hide'
  else
    $('#camera-section').removeClass 'hide'

  if $('#camera_http_jpg span:contains("Not available")').length > 0
    $('#snapshot-section').addClass 'hide'
  else
    $('#snapshot-section').removeClass 'hide'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to extract the logic to a function - you can just use jQuery's `toggle()` method:

```
hideNotAvailableURLS =
  $('#h264-section').toggleClass 'hide', $('#rtsp-value:contains("Not available")').length > 0;
  $('#hls-section').toggleClass 'hide', $('#camera_hls span:contains("Not available")').length > 0;
  $('#rtsp-section').toggleClass 'hide', $('#camera_h264 span:contains("Not available")').length > 0;
  $('#camera-section').toggleClass 'hide', $('#camera_rtmp span:contains("Not available")').length > 0;
  $('#snapshot-section').toggleClass 'hide', $('#camera_http_jpg span:contains("Not available")').length > 0;
```

I don't know coffeeScript syntax, so I've taken a best guess. In JS the toggle call would look like this:

```
$('#h264-section').toggleClass('hide', $('#rtsp-value:contains("Not available")').length > 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also try this bellow code.

```
$(function(){
   $.fn.HideElement = function(){
      var element=$(this);
      element.hide();
    }
});
```

and your javascript code:

```
$("element-selector").HideElement();
```

Comment: So, you've rewritten `$("element-selector").hide()` ?  Only without the jquery standard chaining.

Comment: you can add a common attribute for the selector which are going to be hide when the nested `span` has `"Not available"`. that will be a good option.

Comment: Right, so the idea is that you can add additional logic inside the HideElement function?

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you can use `data-` attributes to pair elements.

You give the section to hide (eg the element with id h261-section) one data value 

(eg `data-pair='h264'`) and a class (eg 'slave') and the control section the same data- value (eg the the element with id rtsp-value) and also give that a class, eg 'control'.

Then you can loop through all the 'control' elements and find their matching 'slave' elements to hide/show.

Example in JS:

```
<div class='control' data-pair='h264'>rtsp</div>
<div class='control' data-pair='hls'>camera_hls</div>

<div class='slave' data-pair='h264' id='h264-section'>h264 section</div>
<div class='slave' data-pair='hls' id='hls-section'>hls section</div>
```

and code:

```
$(".control").each(function() {
    if ($(this).find("span:contains("Not available").length > 0) {
        var pair = $(this).data("pair");
        $(".slave[data-pair='" + pair + "']).hide();            
    } else {
        $(".slave[data-pair='" + pair + "']).show();
    }
});
```

this way, you also never need to change your code as you add new control/slave pairs.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily abstract the repeated search queries into a method to make the code cleaner and easier to read.

```
 hideIfNotAvailable = (toHide, toCheck) ->
   shouldHide = $("#{toCheck}:contains(\"Not available"\)").length is 0
   $(toHide).toggleClass 'hide', shouldHide
```

The above uses coffeescript's string interpolation to abstract away the common part of the search query which you were repeating.
You could then Call it like this:

```
hideNotAvailableURLS = ->
   hideIfNotAvailable '#h264-section', '#rtsp-value'
   hideIfNotAvailable '#hls-section', '#camera_hls'
   hideIfNotAvailable '#rtsp-section', '#camera_h264'
   hideIfNotAvailable '#rtmp-section', '#camera_rtmp'
   hideIfNotAvailable '#camera-section', '#camera_link'
   hideIfNotAvailable '#snapshot-section', '#camera_http_jpg'
```

To improve on this, you could change your HTML Ids, as it's difficult to see the connection between the values you are checking, and the sections they correspond too.
You could use classes instead of unique ids:

```
<a class="link h264">
  H264 (Not Available)
</a>
.
.
.
<div class="section h264">
  This should be hidden
</div>
```

The rest would follow by keeping the `.section` class for the content and the `.link` class for the url.

Then the function would simply be:

```
 hideIfNotAvailable = (name) ->
   shouldHide = $(".link.#{name}:contains(\"Not available"\)").length is 0
   $(".section.#{name}").toggleClass 'hide', shouldHide
```

And you call it in a loop:

```
hideNotAvailableURLS = ->
  sections = ['h264', 'hls', 'rtsp', 'rtmp', 'camera', 'snapshot']
  hideIfNotAvailable(section) for section in sections
```